# Scrivener Appimage graphic display broken after Ubuntu update (Feb 27,2024)

Tags: updates, display, appimage

I am using the Scrivener Linux Beta image on Ubuntu 22.04. I know it is dated, and I have a paid date copy on a Windows 11 machine, but honestly, for first drafts, I just like the calm distraction-free environment of Ubuntu. I have used it for writing for five years now. Windows feels like I'm writing in a preschool daycare center.
I updated Ubuntu on my Lenovo X380 last night and today my Scrivener will not display correctly. Bits of text and the user interface show while most of it is blocked.
So far I have:

- restarted the laptop in the current Ubuntu, again in safe mode, again with the previous kernel to no effect.
- updated libfuse2
- deleted the Appimage and reinstalled it.
- tested the files on Windows and an old X220 with Linux Mint and they work fine in both.
- copied the Appimage from the Mint machine to Ubuntu
- checked other applications on Ubuntu ie. LibreOffice, Scribus, Document Viewer, and others, and they are unaffected.

I don't understand enough about display drivers to know if these could be at fault.
Does anyone have a solution? Reinstalling my instance of Ubuntu 22.04 would not be my preferred option, but I am beginning to think that may be my only option.

Comment: It looks like a Qt theme was applied. Does the problem occur with a new user account?

Comment: I added a guest user account, downloaded the Appimage and it worked perfectly. I've done no theme changes in Extensions or Tweaks in my main account. Any idea how to hunt down and exterminate the bug?

Comment: Delete `~/.cache`, then copy back half of `~/.config ` and `~/.local`. Then post an answer saying which file it was. You could focus on files with Qt in their names

Comment: Just for clarity, you mean delete the whole .cache folder? When I do an ls ~/ .cache I see this anomaly: event-sound-cache.tdb.d1bbc63d36df48f69724fecca15c80d0.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu. everything else looks pretty standard, but I am a pretty casual user with about3-4 bash commands I ever remember because i need them.

Comment: I found a file in Home/.config called Trolltech.conf the first line of which is : [Qt%20Plugin%20Cache%204.8.false] but deleting this file seems to have no effect. I will continue working on this issue tomorrow.

Comment: I suggested deleting the whole cache folder so we don't have to sort through it and decide what to keep. In general, deleting cache is frequently suggested and is safe. I think .config is more likely the problem. Did you perchance try out KDE at any time, which takes control of Qt theme settings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151755/discussion-between-chrisl1954-and-daniel-t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much Daniel T! The problem was in the Scrivener .config file. I deleted .config/Scrivener and .config/trolltech and restarted Scrivener. Scrivener opened and worked normally.